# gcc-4.7 configure install with suffix

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, configuration

I'm running into some problems with building gcc, I **need** to have gcc copy everything with a suffix once it installs. All the executables must have -4.7 on the end so that my default compiler doesn't get screwed around with. Is there an configure variable I can use or something?

Answer (score 2):

GCC's configure script has an option for that: `--program-suffix`, so run something like:

```
./configure --program-suffix="-4.7"
```

See also `./configure -h`.